# Different App settings / environment variables for Virtual applications

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I have a azure web app with 2 deployed web applications. Each in a separate directory as virtual application. Both web applications are almost the same except that they consume different app settings / environment variables `PORTAL_KEY` (like a client switch):
[image]

But both virtual applications will recognize `PORTAL_KEY=Portal1` only. I'd like to differentiate so that the sub folder

- /portal1 gets `PORTAL_KEY=Portal1` and
- /portal2 gets `PORTAL_KEY=Portal2` environment variable.

How can I achieve that without modifying the appsettings.json in each folder (because they will be overwritten by the next web deployment).

Answer (score 1):

All virtual application within one Azure Web App run in the same IIS process (w3wp.exe), and therefore they cannot have different environment variables.

Some possible alternatives:

- Use different app setting keys for each virtual application, e.g. `APP1_PORTAL_KEY` vs `APP2_PORTAL_KEY`. You can create a wrapper in your code that adds the right suffix when you query environments.
- Use different Azure Web Apps for each instead of virtual apps. This gives you the most separation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately your alternatives can't be applied. 1) Using different app setting keys don't work (see question). 2) I would like to use different Azure Web Apps but the customer doesn't.

Comment: @Marcel then the answer is that I don't think what you're asking for is possible

Comment: I guess so. Maybe I try to add different publish profiles pointing to different solution configurations to deploy different appsettings.json with different `PORTAL_KEY`s (like the old web.config transformation did).

Comment: Sure if you're ok storing settings in physical files than you can achieve this.